# REQUIRES_NEW not creating a new transaction in spring+hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have a Spring and hibernate application (both latest version) and I have 2 beans as mentioned below

```
@Component
public class Bean1{

@Autowired 
Bean2 bean2;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void foo()
{
    bean2.bar();
}


@Component
public class Bean2{

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void bar()
{
    try{
           // Do something which throws exception
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log & eat the exception here only.
        But inspite of this the outer transaciton gets rolled back
    }
}
```

The issue is that when `bean2.bar` causes any exception (e.g. foreign `Key ConstraintViolationException`) then it rolls back the outer transaction as well saying " Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only","moreInfo":""}"

On seeing hibernate logs I found only one line for "new transaction"

```
D| o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager- Creating new transaction with name ... PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
```

which means no new transaction is getting created for the inner `bean2.bar();`

I am not able to find out what's wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

REQUIRES_NEW applies to JTA transaction Managers only.
Refer Spring Doc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW)

> **REQUIRES_NEW**
>   `public static final Propagation REQUIRES_NEW`
>
> Execute non-transactionally, suspend the current transaction if one
>   exists. Analogous to EJB transaction attribute of the same name.
>  Note:
>   Actual transaction suspension will not work on out-of-the-box on all
>   transaction managers. This in particular applies to
>   JtaTransactionManager, which requires the
>   javax.transaction.TransactionManager to be made available it to it
>   (which is server-specific in standard J2EE).